# How to get ListProperty's index in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am working with the RecycleView's data and trying to extract its data index.

For example: we have `lst = ListProperty([{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}])`, then how do we get the `{"b":2}` index?

I tried find the data index via `data.find({"b":2})`and the system return `AttributeError: 'ObservableList' object has no attribute 'find'`

I have taken a look at the [source code](https://github.com/nuigroup/kivy/blob/master/kivy/properties.pyx) and didn't find any method to get the data's index by calling out the content in it (such as find()).

So my question is there any way to get the RecycleView's data index like the given example?

(of course, I can just do `lst[1]` but the data updates every milliseconds which the reason why I have to find its index via its contents)

.

Comment: from your statement :
can just do lst[1]
i assume print (lst) will output :  [{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}]
if so, you can find the data by key, like this:
your_list = [{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}]


c = [c for c in your_list if 'b' in c]
print (c[0])

output:
{'b': 2}

Comment: @HenroSutrisnoTanjung Appreciates that, but I just worry that using for loop will cause some performance issues when the data is up to thousands and being updated in milliseconds. . . Which is the reason why I write this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [index()](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method. In a method of the class that has the `ListProperty`, you can do:

```
self.lst.index({'b': 2})
```